# How to chmod +x a file in Windows, for use in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, chmod

I have a file that needs to be executable in Linux, which I'd do by using `chmod +x` when using Linux.

My problem is: this file is compiled in Windows, and it's a pain to have to open my Ubuntu VM to just `chmod` it.

Is there a tool, or a method in Windows to allow me to add the `+x` permission to the file, so it is executable upon receipt to a Linux machine?

I've tried searching SU and Google, but I'm only seeing irrelevant results about how `chmod` doesn't exist on Windows, and to use file permissions instead - but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: prepending a script [see here](http://askubuntu.com/a/25690/479118) might  be a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key phrase in your question is "executable upon receipt", and the answer depends on how it's being received. If you send a tarball, you can have some executable files in it. A single file could be mailed in `uuencode` format with `begin 755 filename` in the header. If you provide more details on what tools you have available on the sending side, we might be able to find a way to make it work.

Comment: I thought of using a `tar` archive, but my problem is getting it to be `+x` in the first place. Basically, I do all of my development on a Windows machine. It's a project using Adobe AIR, and in that is a requirement to use the `NativeProcess` class. In doing so, an `exe` is launched on Windows, and the binary on Linux. It's that binary that needs to be `+x`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like an [`untar`](https://code.google.com/p/as3-simple-untar/) package is available for AIR. I could put the executable in a tar archive, then untar it on installation.

Comment: For tar, look at my old time favourite [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) (Linux command as .exe's under Windows. No cygwin or similar required.)

Answer (score 8):

```
git update-index --chmod=+x myfile.sh
```

from https://www.scivision.dev/git-windows-chmod-executable/

Comment: This only applies when using Git and committing a script for later use in Linux.  Not what the question asked, but this is what I was looking for.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476513/git-file-permissions-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

`chmod +x` sets attribute in the filesystem and is not assiciated with the file itself. So, there is no way to do that you want.

Comment: That isn't entirely true as VCS (e.g. git) keeps track of execution rights.