# Allow chmod on CIFS mount

Tags: cifs

I have a Windows 7 host, with a CentOS 6 guest under VirtualBox.

I have a Windows directory shared with the Linux guest using CIFS.

Everything worked fine so far, until I realized that all `chmod` operations yield:

> chmod: changing permissions of `x': Operation not permitted

This is understandable, but my problem is that some tools I have no control on, attempt to `chmod` files for me, and fail as a result.

**Is it possible to *allow* but *ignore* all `chmod()` calls on a CIFS mount?** Please note than these calls are made from a programming language and not from the command-line `chmod` utility.

Edit: [the manual for mount.cifs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html#id2532725) says (emphasize mine):

> The core CIFS protocol does not provide unix ownership information or mode for files and directories. Because of this, files and directories will generally appear to be owned by whatever values the uid= or gid= options are set, and will have permissions set to the default file_mode and dir_mode for the mount. **Attempting to change these values via chmod/chown will return success but have no effect.**

That's exactly the behaviour I'm after then, so why is it not working for me?

Comment: Please could you clarify **what** programming language, and what you are actually trying to achieve with the *programming* language.  *Allow* but *ignore* on the face of it seems to be contradictory.  With further background will help us provide insight into your problem.

Comment: I don't think you can get all permissions modifications to be ignored . . . does the script actually bail out when the file permissions are modified, or does it bail out later as the permissions are not sufficient?  If they're not sufficient, you could use mount options (file_mode and dir_mode) to set all the files to have the permissions you need . . .

Comment: @David Again I don't have control over the tool, which I believe is programmed in C, and makes calls to the system's `chmod()` function. @ernie It bails out when the file permissions are (trying to be) modified, and does not complete.

Comment: For information, I'm trying to install a [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) package for PHP over [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), and the script fails because its [PHAR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) package installer tries to `chmod()` some files. The exact error is: *Extraction from phar "..." failed: Cannot extract "package.xml" to "...", setting file permissions failed*.

Comment: Thanks, this was the background that we where looking for.  Can you add additional permissions on your Windows system to permit what is happening in the install script?  It sounds almost as though the script is trying to set something to executable, which just may not work on a windows share.

Comment: @David I don't know what to try or how to do this, that's precisely why I'm asking the question :)

Comment: What is your mount command?

Comment: @David here is the `fstab` entry: `//192.168.56.1/www /mnt/www cifs username=www,password=xxx,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it: the `noperm` mount parameter does exactly this:

```
//192.168.56.1/www /mnt/www cifs noperm,username=www,password=xxx, ...
```

Note that `mount -a` does not apply the parameter, you have to reboot to make it work.
It took me a lot of trial and error to figure this out.

Now `chmod` works fine, the command does not yield any error, and is just ignored.

Comment: Why reboot when you can just unmount and mount again? Maybe CIFS can even remount.

Comment: Shouldn't `mount -a` unmount and remount as well?

Comment: No. That would be fatal. It only mounts currently unmounted filesystems from `/etc/fstab`

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having using python's `shutil.copytree(src,dst)` where `dst` is on a CIFS mount. Internally, `shutil`'s low-level copy function does a `chmod` on `dst` after the copy. The solution here is much preferred to catching and ignoring the `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted` that python was producing.

Comment: Thanks this worked great for a program that was out of my control trying to change permissions on a CIFS mount

Answer (score 0):

Try adding exec option.  I believe mounting as a non-root user will turn off exec.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34822/is-it-possible-to-enable-execution-of-files-from-a-cifs-mount-in-bash

Comment: Same thing I'm afraid with `exec`: *operation not permitted*.

Comment: try mounting as root?

Comment: Well, looking at a couple further articles, you can not chmod +x to a file on a windows share.  You have marked all the files as executable  by using using the option `file_mode=0777` anyway.  I would suggest installing the pear module on a folder in the linux file system, then copy it over.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

   http://superuser.com/questions/624368/how-to-chmod-x-a-file-in-windows-for-use-in-linux